# What does ID3DX11EffectVariable::AsSharedResource() do?

Tags: c++, direct3d

I saw this code line in the Direct3D SDK and I want to know what id does exactly. Does it convert from object type to another object type, or set data, or what?

```
ID3DX11Effect effect ;
ID3DX11EffectShaderResourceVariable var ;

var = effect->GetVariableByName ( "texture_obj" )->AsShaderResource() ;
```

`GetVariableByName()` has `ID3DX11EffectVariable` type .

My question is about the second part `AsShaderResource()`: does it convert the `ID3DX11EffectVariable` to `ID3DX11EffectShaderResourceVariable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it converts the effect's variable into a shader resource variable.

See the [MS specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (section 'Remarks').